# Tracking original referrer in GA when using SagePay Form integration

Tags: google-analytics, payment-gateway, opayo, referrals

When using the [SagePay Form integration](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document/form-integration), the referrer in Google Analytics always shows as **live.sagepay.com** rather than the original referrer. This is because, when using this integration method, the user gets redirected to live.sagepay.com to complete the payment process before getting redirected back to the original website.

Since the payment templates on SagePay don't allow external scripts, we can't add the analytics tracking script here, which means cross-domain tracking is out of the question.

Is there a workaround for this problem? As many payment gateways are external and behave in a similar way I'm guessing this must be a fairly common issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a referral exclusion in the Google Analytics account itself. This should prevent new sessions being created as per the docs:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en